# Interlacing sequences by polynomials?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, polynomials, approximation-theory

Given $t=2^\ell$ where $\ell\in\mathbb N_{>0}$ and $M\in\mathbb Z$ and two sets of integers $\{a_1,\dots,a_t\}$ and $\{b_1,\dots,b_t\}$ with $0<a_1\leq \dots\leq a_t<M$ and $0<b_1\leq \dots\leq b_t<M$ we can find polynomials $f,g\in\mathbb Z[x]$ such that

$$f(a_i)<g(b_{i})<f(a_{i+1})<g(b_{i+1})$$ holds at every $i\in\{1,\dots,t-1\}$.

> How small will $\max(f_\infty,g_\infty)$ be when $$d_{\max{}}=\max(\mathsf{deg}(f),\mathsf{deg}(g))=O(h(t))$$ where $f_\infty$ and $g_\infty$ refers to largest coefficient by magnitude and $h:\mathbb N_{\geq0}\rightarrow\mathbb N_{\geq0}$ is a strictly increasing function?

I am interested in whether it would be possible that $\max(f_\infty,g_\infty)$ exists at $h(t)=(\log t)^{\alpha}$ at fixed $\alpha\geq0$ and if it exists whether it is bound by $2^{(\log (tM))^\beta}$ at fixed $\beta\geq0$.

> Is there good references?

Comment: Version twelve.